# bash add array to plist

Tags: bash, post-install

I'm making a installable package via Cydia that will write com.intelliborn.intelliscreenx
to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Hidden</key>
    <array>
        <string>libactivator</string>
        <string>com.aaronash.BarrelSettings</string>
        <string>com.iptm.bigboss.sbsettings</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But I don't know how to write to postinst script to where it add's it correctly and make the postrmv script to where it removes it correctly.

The hidden.plist should look like this after installing this package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Hidden</key>
    <array>
        <string>libactivator</string>
        <string>com.aaronash.BarrelSettings</string>
        <string>com.iptm.bigboss.sbsettings</string>
            <string>com.intelliborn.intelliscreenx</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Here how my postinst & postrmv scripts look:

postinst

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)

if [[ $1 == install ]]; then
    if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
        eval "echo 'finish:restart' >&${cydia[0]}"
    fi
fi
echo -e "\n\<string>com.intelliborn.intelliscreenx</string>\n" >> /var/mobile/Library/LibHide/hidden.plist

exit 0
```

postrmv

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " " >> /var/mobile/Library/LibHide/
sed -i 's/<string>com.intelliborn.intelliscreenx</string>\n" >> /var/mobile/Library/LibHide/hidden.plist

declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)

if [[ $1 == install ]]; then
    if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
        eval "echo 'finish:restart' >&${cydia[0]}"
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plutil for iPhone as it works for plists files.

In your control file for your cydia package add the following to your pre-depends like the following example so that if plutil is installed before hand it can be installed for the postinst and postrm not to fail.

**control**

```
Name: com.test.package
Pre-Depends: com.ericasadun.utilities
```

**postinst**

```
#!/bin/bash

#add value to array
plutil -key Hidden -arrayadd -value com.intelliborn.intelliscreenx /var/mobile/Library/LibHide/hidden.plist

declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)

if [[ $1 == install ]]; then
    if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
    eval "echo 'finish:restart' >&${cydia[0]}"
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. i don't see arrayadd as a valid option

Comment: you have to make sure you have the updated plutil. Grab it http://ericasadun.com/ftp/EricaUtilities/ otherwise you'll have to search for it.